# When using auth0, I cannot gain access to the scope read:current_user

Tags: javascript, auth0

I would like to be able to view and update a user's metadata from a single page application but whenever I attempt to gain access to any of the scopes that would appear from the documentation (https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/auth0js/v9)

However, when I run the following code:

```
webAuth.checkSession(
  {
    audience: `https://mysite.eu.auth0.com/api/v2/`,
    scope: "read:current_user"
  },
  (err, result) => {
    err && console.log("err", err");
    result && console.log("result", result);
  }
);
```

I get the following error:

```
{error: "consent_required", error_description: "Consent required"}
```

I've tried putting the scope `read:current_user` in multiple places but it always appears to fail.

Answer (score 1):

The error means that the server is requesting an additional consent from the user, so `checkSession` cannot complete the action because it happens silently and cannot prompt the user.

To fix this, go to Auth0 dashboard -> APIs -> Auth0 Management API -> Settings tab -> uncheck 'Allow Skipping User Consent'.